# How to configure Sonarqube for PHP projects?

Tags: php, sonarqube, sonar-runner

Trying to setup [Sonarqube](https://www.sonarqube.org/) for PHP code base for codecoverage analysis.
I have modified the sonar-scanner.properties file with the following configuration.

```
Path = sonar-scanner-2.8\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
sonar.projectKey=PhpProject
sonar.projectName=PhpProject
sonar.language=php
sonar.sources=C:/Users/Hameetha/Downloads/SonarSource-sonar-examples-4.5-21-gbb6c0f9/SonarSource-sonar-examples-bb6c0f9/projects/languages/php/php-sonar-runner-unit-tests
sonar.scm.provide=sonarphp
```

however when running the sonar-scanner the following error msg is shown.

[image]

Comment: You should define this info in sonar-project.properties, not scanner. See https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScanner-Use

Answer (score 3):

Having a closer look to the console, you'll see the following message : **You must install a plugin that supports the language 'php'**.

So all you need to do is to install the SonarPHP plugin: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarPHP

Comment: i have installed the plugin as mentioned in the documentation, inspite of it get the same error

Answer (score 0):

The filename is incorrect. It is not sonar-scanner.properties it is sonar-project.properties. That might well be your problem.